# simple angular filter on name doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am simply trying to filter a list of contacts on the name but it doesn't work

In header:

```
<div ng-controller="headerController">
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
```

The list:

```
<div class="list">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="p in people | filter : search">
  <a href ng-click='selectContact(p)'>{{p.name}}</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

See my plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/BXSWQ9?p=preview

Comment: Because your search value is undefined in your list view

Comment: Thank you @Zooly. then if I initialize the search variable in my peopleController then it works but after if I change the value it doesn't refresh. How can I have the list refreshed please ?

Comment: OK finally I removed my headerController, I think I might not need it and it is working without it. I guess I could have it worked with this controller as well but right now it is OK for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your top.html erase the ng-controller, just like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
```

And it will work.